# 'priorities' tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The [priorities](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/priorities) tag, q.v., has hitherto been for questions of the form "should one do A or B?" (where A and B are both good, or both bad). It recently got used for [two](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13553) [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7097) about the *halacha* of prioritizing a *kohen*. I can think of a few ways to go about this:

- Broaden the scope of the tag to include both choice-of-what-to-do and *kohen*-first questions.
- Narrow the tag's scope to choice-of-what-to-do questions and

  - possibly rename it and/or
  - possibly make a new tag for prioritizing a *kohen* (and others, I suppose).

There may be more ways.

I've detagged the two questions it was added to (re *kohen*) as a temporary stopgap, but am bringing the issue here. Please post solutions as answers.

---

**Update:** The use of the tag has broadened further. Now it's used also for "should I do X before Y or Y before X?"-type questions.

Comment: Are there enough precedence-of-kohanim questions to rate a tag?

Comment: @MonicaCellio As of now, no. But the proposed tag below would likely cover other questions that have to do with precedance of different things and may even take some questions from the priorities tag now that the tags are better defined. (This is all how I assume the other side would view it.)

Comment: @msh210 Well I'd say this has been pretty successful :)

Comment: @DoubleAA `:-/` If we don't get any votes for my answer or yours within a few days (both now have 0), I'll _bl"n_ revert my edits to the two questions in question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it all fits in one tag, but if we do make a new tag I think it should be [precedence-kedimah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/precedence-kedimah).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the word "priorities" is not a very helpful name for the tag. All of the different ways that people have been using the tag are indeed different applications of the word "priorities." But if we want the tag to mean something specific, we should give it a more specific name. I believe the intention behind the tag is something like "hierarchy-of-importance" or something like that (I welcome any other suggestions for names). "Priorities" could be a synonym of the renamed tag.

Whatever the new name is, this tag definitely needs a descriptive tag wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I think "precedence of a kohein" (or other group) is not a useful tag concept.  If you care about precedence of a kohein, it will be in *some context*, and it's the context that will be the driver for the question.  Further, we have the [kohen-priest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kohen-priest) tag, which seems relevant.  For those rare occasions where you want to find questions specifically about *priorities* involving kohanim, there's always search.

If we have a tag for the "priorities of mitzvot" concept, it should be narrow, as described in the question.  But I'm not convinced we even need the tag, and would like to hear comments from people who have used it to find, rather than create, questions or answers.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph: good point, and I'll now delete my own answer suggesting that _kohen_-precedence questions have their own tag. (And your second paragraph is definitely food for thought and/or research.)